# Is it true that those who do more sins die late in life after suffering too much?

Tags: karma, sin, death

Is it true that those who do more sins though get material gains in life but die late in life ,after becoming old and suffering too much ?

Though they also go to hell after death but they also suffer too much in old age before dying ?

Is this written in any scripture ?

Comment: If this is the case there are a couple ppl in my family who should live to be 150 yrs old hahaha